# Validating HTML forms with PHP

Tags: php, html, validation

I am trying to validate that there has been some input in the text fields for the shipping details in Step 3 of this script, in other words they are not left empty. Where I'm struggling is where to put the validation script.  I keep going back and forth between putting something in the "processStep3" function and the "displayStep3" function but have yet to succeed. I understand how to validate a form if its just one page, but now that I've broken this out into multiple steps I no longer understand where my script needs to go!

//**RESOLVED**
I needed to add the validation code to the processStep3() function using if(empty($_POST["value"])  I doubt this is the best way to go about doing what I'm doing but it works!!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Mid-Term Practical</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css" />
      </head>
      <body>


    <?php

    if ( isset( $_POST["step"] ) and $_POST["step"] >= 1 and $_POST["step"] <= 5 ) {
      call_user_func( "processStep" . (int)$_POST["step"] );
    } else {
      displayStep1();
    }


    function setValue( $fieldName ) {
      if ( isset( $_POST[$fieldName] ) ) {
        echo $_POST[$fieldName];
      }
    }

    function setChecked( $fieldName, $fieldValue ) {
      if ( isset( $_POST[$fieldName] ) and $_POST[$fieldName] == $fieldValue ) {
        echo ' checked="checked"';
      }
    }

    function setSelected( $fieldName, $fieldValue ) {
      if ( isset( $_POST[$fieldName] ) and $_POST[$fieldName] == $fieldValue ) {
        echo ' selected="selected"';
      }
    }

    function processStep1() {
      displayStep2();
    }


    function processStep2() {
      if ( isset( $_POST["submitButton"] ) and $_POST["submitButton"] == "< Back" ) {
        displayStep1();
      } else {
        displayStep3();
      }
    }

        function processStep3() {

    if( isset( $_POST["submitButton"] ) and $_POST["submitButton"] == "Cancel" ) {
    displayStep1();
  } elseif ( isset( $_POST["submitButton"] ) and $_POST["submitButton"] == "< Back" ){
    displayStep2();
  } else {
        if( empty($_POST["city"]) || empty($_POST["zip"]) || empty($_POST["email"])) {
            displayStep3();
            echo "

            <div style='float: left;'>
            <p style='background: red; color: white;'>Please enure all required fields (*) are filled out then re submit the form</p>
            </div>";
        } else {
            displayStep4();
        }

    }
}



    function processStep4() {
        if ( isset( $_POST["submitButton"] ) and $_POST["submitButton"] == "< Cancel" ) {
            displayStep1();
        } else {
            displayThanks();
        }
    }

    function displayStep1() {
    ?>
        <h1>Please Select an Item:</h1>

        <form action="midterm-practical.php" method="post">
          <div style="width: 40em;">
            <input type="hidden" name="step" value="1" />



            <label for="item1">Moroccan Mint: $9.99</label>
                <input type="radio" name="item" id="item1" value="Moroccan Mint"<?php setChecked( "item", "Moroccan Mint" )?>/>
                <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price1" value="9.99"<?php setValue( "price", "9.99" )?> />

            <label for="item2">Peppermint: $8.99</label>
                <input type="radio" name="item" id="item2" value="Peppermint"<?php setChecked( "item", "Peppermint" )?>/>
                <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price1" value="8.99"<?php setValue( "price", "8.99" )?> />

            <label for="item3">Citron Green: $9.99</label>
                <input type="radio" name="item" id="item3" value="Citron Green"<?php setChecked( "item", "Citron Green" )?>/>
                <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price1" value="9.99"<?php setValue( "price", "9.99" )?> />

            <label for="item4">All About Adam: $10.99</label>
                <input type="radio" name="item" id="item4" value="All About Adam"<?php setChecked( "item", "All About Adam" )?>/>
                <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price1" value="10.99"<?php setValue( "price", "10.99" )?> />

            <label for="item5">Detox Herbal: $12.99</label>
                <input type="radio" name="item" id="item5" value="Detox Herbal"<?php setChecked( "item", "Detox Herbal" )?>/>
                <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price1" value="12.99"<?php setValue( "price", "12.99" )?> />

            <label for="item6">Serenity: $7.99</label>
                <input type="radio" name="item" id="item6" value="Serenity"<?php setChecked( "item", "Serenity" )?>/>
                <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price1" value="7.99"<?php setValue( "price", "7.99" )?> />

            <label for="item7">Spiced Chai Black: $8.99</label>
                <input type="radio" name="item" id="item7" value="Spiced Chai Black"<?php setChecked( "item", "Spiced Chai Black" )?>/>
                <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price1" value="8.99"<?php setValue( "price", "8.99" )?> />

            <label for="item8">Spiced Chai Rooibos: $10.99</label>
                <input type="radio" name="item" id="item8" value="Spiced Chai Rooibos"<?php setChecked( "item", "Spiced Chai Rooibos" )?>/>
                <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price1" value="10.99"<?php setValue( "price", "10.99" )?> />

            <label for="item9">Chamomile: $6.99</label>
                <input type="radio" name="item" id="item9" value="Chamomile"<?php setChecked( "item", "Chamomile" )?>/>
                <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price1" value="6.99"<?php setValue( "price", "6.99" )?> />

            <label for="item10">Earl Grey Lavender: $11.99</label>
                <input type="radio" name="item" id="item10" value="Earl Grey Lavender"<?php setChecked( "item", "Earl Grey Lavender" )?>/>
                <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price1" value="11.99"<?php setValue( "price", "11.99" )?> />

            <div style="clear: both;">
              <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="nextButton" value="Next &gt;" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    <?php
    }

    function displayStep2() {
    ?>
        <h1>Item Quantity</h1>

        <form action="midterm-practical.php" method="post">
          <div style="width: 30em;">
            <input type="hidden" name="step" value="2" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php setValue( "item" ) ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php setValue( "price" ) ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php setValue( "city" ) ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="state" value="<?php setValue( "state") ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="<?php setValue( "zip" ) ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php setValue( "email" ) ?>" />

            <label for="item">Item in Cart:</label> 

            <?php echo setValue( "item" ) ?>

            <label for="quantity">Please Choose a Quantity:</label>
                <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="<?php setValue( "quantity" ) ?>" />



            <div style="clear: both;">
              <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="nextButton" value="Next &gt;" />
              <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="backButton" value="&lt; Back" style="margin-right: 20px;" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    <?php
    }

    function displayStep3() {


    ?>
        <h1>Your Cart and Shipping Details</h1>
        <form action="midterm-practical.php" method="post">
        <style type="text/css">
            .error{ background: #d33; color: white; padding: 0.2em; }
        </style>
          <div style="width: 30em;">
            <input type="hidden" name="step" value="3" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php setValue( "item" ) ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php setValue( "price" )?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php setValue( "city" ) ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="state" value="<?php setValue( "state") ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="<?php setValue( "zip" ) ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php setValue( "email" ) ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<?php setValue( "quantity" ) ?>" />

            <h4>Item(s) in Cart:</h4>
            <br />
            <p><?php echo setValue( "item" ) ?>
            <br />
            Quantity:<?php echo setValue( "quantity" ) ?>
            <br />
            Cost: $<?php echo setValue( "price" ) ?> ea.
            <br /></p>


            <h3>Please Enter Your Shipping Address</h3>
            <label for="city"> City *</label>
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="<?php setValue( "city" )?>" />


            <label for="state">State *</label>
            <select name="state" id="state" size="1">
              <option value="Ohio"<?php setSelected( "state", "Ohio" ) ?>>Ohio</option>
              <option value="Kentucky"<?php setSelected( "state", "Kentucky" ) ?>>Kentucky</option>
              <option value="Indiana"<?php setSelected( "state", "Indiana" ) ?>>Indiana</option>
            </select>

            <label for="zip">Zip *</label>
                <input type="number" name="zip" id="zip" value="<?php setValue( "zip" )?>" />

            <label for="email">Email *</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php setValue( "email" )?>" />


            <div style="clear: both;">
              <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="nextButton" value="Finalize Order &gt;" />
              <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="backButton" value="&lt; Back" />
              <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" style="margin-right: 20px;" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    <?php
    }

    function displayStep4() {
    $subTotal = $_POST["price"] * $_POST["quantity"];
    $tax = $subTotal * .06;
    $noTax = 0;
    $total = $subTotal + $tax;
    $ohio = "Ohio";
    ?>
        <h1>Process Order</h1>
        <form action="midterm-practical.php" method="post">
            <div style="width: 30em;">
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="4" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php setValue( "item" ) ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php setValue( "price" ) ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php setValue( "city" ) ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="state" value="<?php setValue( "state") ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="<?php setValue( "zip" ) ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php setValue( "email" ) ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<?php setValue( "quantity" ) ?>" />


                <p>
                    Sub Total: $<?php echo number_format($subTotal, 2) ?>
                    <br />
                    Tax: $<?php if ( $_POST["state"] == $ohio){
                    echo number_format($tax, 2);} else { echo number_format( $noTax, 0); };?>
                    <br />
                    Order Total: $<?php echo number_format($total, 2) ?>
                </p>



            <div style="clear: both;">
              <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="sendOrder" value="Process Order &gt;" />
              <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="backButton" value="&lt; Cancel" style="margin-right: 20px;" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

    <?php
    }

    function displayThanks() {
    $date = date('m-d-Y', strtotime('+5 days'));
    $subTotal = $_POST["price"] * $_POST["quantity"];
    $tax = $subTotal * .06;
    $noTax = 0;
    $total = $subTotal + $tax;
    $ohio = "Ohio";

    ?>
        <form action="midterm-practical.php" method="post">
            <div style="width: 30em;">
                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="4" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item" value="<?php setValue( "item" ) ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php setValue( "price" ) ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php setValue( "city" ) ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="state" value="<?php setValue( "state") ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="<?php setValue( "zip" ) ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php setValue( "email" ) ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<?php setValue( "quantity" ) ?>" />


        <h1>Thank You</h1>
        <p>You ordered <?php echo setValue( "quantity" ) ?> boxes of <?php echo setValue("item")?> Tea
        <br />
        <br />
        <strong>Total Cost:</strong> <br />

                    Sub Total: $<?php echo number_format($subTotal, 2) ?>
                    <br />
                    Tax: $<?php if ( $_POST["state"] == $ohio){
                    echo number_format($tax, 2);} else { echo number_format( $noTax, 0); };?>
                    <br />
                    Order Total: $<?php echo number_format($total, 2) ?>
                </p>




        <p>Your order has been received.
        Your item(s) should arrive by <br /><?php echo $date?>. </p>

            </div>
        </form>
    <?php
    }
    function displayError() {
    ?>
    <form action="midterm-practical.php" action="post">
    <h1>There seems to be an issue with form you submitted.  Please make sure all required fields(*) are filled out.</h1>
    </form>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why not validate client side? Use Javscript/Jquery?

Comment: I'm not there yet.  I'm working my way through this book and would like to not start implementing new things util I have the basics of this down.

Comment: @Mark - because some people have javascript turned off. You can validate client-side, but you can't rely on it.

Comment: Do not implement validation through JavaScript, this is a terrible idea, people can disable JavaScript and therefore disable any validation/security you have used JavaScript. Thought I'd just add that as I saw the top reply.

Comment: Validation and security are two completely different things. For validation (something that is not crucial to the system), the use of Javascript is not a terrible idea.

Comment: But from a user experience pov, it's better to be told if your not meeting validation before submission

Comment: @Mark Surely it is. But, for example, on huge systems, you may prefer to leave the validation on the client-side, so you don't overload the server. I'm not saying it's the best way of doing these stuff, but it's not a terrible idea that should never be used.

Comment: @Mark - You are entirely correct. Validate client side if you can, but you need to check server-side too. A previous job involved supporting a website which needed to be as accessible as possible, and a lot of screen reader software ignores javascript completely.

Comment: @afuzzyllama The kind of validation I'm talking about is something like a missing field on a form, some text field with missing characters, and so on. Crucial validation are not included, as I told before.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to work with PHP.

The most common one is the do-it-all on the same script which will require you to validate each form on the same file.

The other one, least common, but more efficient and kinda hard if you're new to programming is the OOP(Object Oriented Programming) way.

If you're starting off, try the first one.

If you have your validation script, you can just include it on your other files by the following command:

```
require_once 'validation.php';
```

Assuming of course your validation script is indeed called validation.

The you can just call each function everytime there is a submit like this:

```
//Call function to validate email: 

require_once 'validation.php';

if(isset($_POST['submitForm'])){
    //call your functions to validate here
    validateEmail($_POST['usermail']);
}
```

It's pretty simple once you get the hold of it.

Comment: @YiseraIf I understand:
So I would write a separate script file just for validation and include it in the same folder as my form script. Then in the function to processStep3 I would include a call to the validation script and within that if the submitButton is clicked call the functions to validate the indiviual fields?

Comment: @ryroanderson pretty much something like that. Though, If I were you, I wouldn't be doing the following:  $_POST["submitButton"] == "< Back" because that can somehow go wrong.